# Overriding move-assignement operator

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I get a warning from clang-tidy when overriding the move-assignment operator in a subclass and moving the fields of the sub class after invoking the move-assignment operator of the base class.

Example:

```
class Base{
     ...
     Base& operator=(Base&& other) {...}
};

class Sub : public Base {
     OtherClass n;
     Sub& operator=(Sub&& other) {
         Base::operator=(std::move(other));
         n = std::move(other.n); // <-- Here is the warning
         return *this;
     }
};
```

The warning I get is:

```
Clang-Tidy: 'other' used after it was moved
```

What is the correct way to override the operator?

Comment: Show the warning you get?

Comment: What warning???

Comment: Control flow reaches end of the function without return statement while function is supposed to return a reference to `Sub`. This causes Undefined Behaviour. Clang-Tidy warning is pretty much useless.

Comment: Uh, this isn't a duplicate of that question at all...

Comment: @VTT i wanted to show some sample code and not copy code from my project i fix the missing return. this has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: clang-tidy seems wrong. Maybe you can appease it by swapping the 2 lines? Or use `Base::operator=(static_cast<Base&&>(other))`.

Comment: @peter Code sample is supposed to be [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can't just crop everything. Also I didn't vote to close as duplicate...

Comment: @MarcGlisse thanks for these tips :) both remove the warning

Comment: @VTT yeah you are correct and i fixed the missing return statement.

Comment: I don't get the duplicate.. My question is about the operator and not the constructor.